# Microsoft / Botbuilder for NodeJS: Bind URL Parameters to bot session

Tags: nodejs

### SDK

- Referencia: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder
- SDK Platform: Node.js
- SDK Version: 3.14.0

### Descripcion

Hola! Hace ya varios dias que vengo investigando este tema sin encontrar respuesta.
Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de leer parametros de URL desde el objeto de session del usuario del BotFramework de Microsoft para NodeJs

Por ejemplo, si accedo a la siguiente URL de mi chatbot:

```
http://localhost:3978/api/messages?pronuntiation=british
```

¿Hay alguna forma de leer el parametro "pronuntiation" desde el objeto "session" como se lee a continuacion?

```
bot.dialog("/", function(session){
    var desiredPronuntiation = session.someUrlParameters.pronuntiation;
    if( desiredPronuntiation == "british"){
          ///blah
    }
});
```

Se que esto se puede hacer con el SDK de C#, pero realmente queria tratar de hacerlo con NodeJs...

Ya debugie el flujo desde `server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen())` hasta el metodo `ChatConnector.verifyBotFramework()` donde termine viendo que finalmente se termina llamando a un metodo `_this.dispatch(req.body, res, next);` (ChatbotConnector.js en la linea 149) donde se pasa el post body pero no el objeto request.

Por eso a primera vista no lo veo posible, pero quisas me equivoco y queria consultar si alguien sabe mas del tema.

Gracias,
Luis

Comment: Saludos bro! bienvenido, esto es StackOverflow en Español, versión hispana :D traduce por favor

Comment: ¡Traducido! No se en que momento me enviaron a SO en español...